# STM32CubeMX inform me that "The pin is affected with an I/O function", what does that mean?

Tags: arm, stm32

When I use STM32CubeMX to configure my STM32F105 project, the generated report shows me a warning message for all GPIO pins I set----"The pin is affected with an I/O function", can someone tell me what does that mean? Can I ignore this warning message?

See the following link for the report:
[Configuration Report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdmh5am6yaubn4r/WZ001REC.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: It is not a warning, but it inform you that this pin is controlled as standard GPIO and is not connected to any other peripheral. You can control or read this pin as you want.

Comment: Great, thank you, vlk!